# Finding all suffix starting with a character X

Tags: c, linux

I need to find all suffix starting with a character X. For example, `for int suffix (char str [], char c)` when the word is `ababcd` and the letter `b` it should return:

```
babcd
bcd
```

and the number 2.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char str[128];
    int counter=0;
    printf ("Please enter charachter and a string \n");
    scanf("%c %s",&c,str);
    counter = my_suffix(str,c);
    printf("The string has %d suffix \n",counter);
    return 0;
}

int my_suffix(char str[],char c) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == c)
        {   puts(str+i);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I couldn't find why it's not running,

Thanks!

Comment: ***I couldn't find why it's not running,*** This is what a debugger will help you with. Are there any compile errors? Obviously it won't run if it does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine you should just written following method above `int main()`

```
int my_suffix(char str[],char c){...}
```